# Is there any way to do server side rendering with pure node.js/react without express.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, server-side-rendering

All the examples I've seen for server side rendering involve express.js similar to this example, in the server.js file:

```js
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import express from "express";

import App from "../src/App";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("./public/index.html"), "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send("An error occurred");
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
      )
    );
  });
});

app.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, ".", "dist"), { maxAge: "30d" })
);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

But I was wondering if this can be achieved purely with node.js. I don't see why it can't. But when I tried writing it in with require() functions and node modules I never could get it working. Does anyone have a working solution of what could be done, to both import the App.js from react front end, and to write this code purely in node.js

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Express is just a JS package to simplify certain workflow, in this case, listening and responding to an http request.
So yes, you can do it without using express.
A simple internet search will show some tutorials.
Below are top 2 results from Duck Duck Go search of "nodejs how to serve without express".

- https://medium.com/khojchakra/a-simple-nodejs-server-without-express-js-6773122d365f
- https://medium.com/@amitgupta15/node-js-server-without-express-bf22903355ad

Comment: But how do you serve the React <App/> THere's alot of steps that goes into it. I probably don't have the technical capability.

Comment: Now, why is it that you're willing to use React package but not express? Please be clear of what you're trying to accomplish here. If you follow the first tutorial, you will see that you write header, body and call end() to respond to an http request where as you would just call send() with express. All express does is hide those abstract from you. If you really want to know how follow these tutorials until you get those detail steps.

Comment: I'm trying to get a better understanding of Node.js, since express pretty much uses Node.js. Also I like more control over the server code than what express alots. I'm simply trying to do server side rendering, but with node.js and react, instead of express.js and react. When I tried writing it all out with node.js, it failed and I'm not sure how to diagnose.

Comment: So here's my 2 cents. Use express. It will most likely have API for whatever granular settings you need to do. It should get you started faster. There are express replacement packages like fastify if you're looking for more performant version. If you're really inclined to get your hands dirty with http request, look at node.js document on http or even express package repo source code along with tutorials on node.js http request/response.

Comment: node.js http doc link: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html, express repo link: https://github.com/expressjs/express

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing, just reading node.js docs for now.

Comment: Why does everyone hate Node.js? It's not that different from express.

Comment: @RodionN. I don't think people hate it. It's just simpler to get start with. It's all about balance when using any packages. Do I want to re-invent to wheel for that feature? Or should I just use package A to save some dev time. I think express falls into a category where using it is a no brainer. Not all node.js devs need to know all the features of node.js.

Comment: Yeah that's true. It's good for people to not re-invent the wheel. I'm just using node.js so I understand and know what that wheel actually is haha.